# TSQL inter-table updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, a contacts table and an addresses table.
The addresses table contains a contact id, and 4 address lines.
I wish to update the contacts table with the information from the addresses table.
For simplicity's sake let the tables be as follows:

addresses(
. contact int not null,
. address1 varchar(32) not null,
. address2 varchar(32) not null
)

contacts(
. id int primary key,
. addr1 varchar(32) not null,
. addr2 varchar(32) not null
)

How (int tsql) do I update the contacts table from the addresses table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. Your schema is broken. You are repeating the address data in more than one place.

Your schema should be something like

```
addresses(
. id int primary key,
. address1 varchar(32) not null,
. address2 varchar(32) not null
)

contacts(
.id int primary key
.addressId int foreign key (addresses.id)
}
```

So to get a contact's address, you would perform a join as follows:

```
select 
    c.id contactId,
    a.address1,
    a.address2 
from 
    contacts c 
    join addresses a on 
        c.addressId=a.id 
where 
    c.id=@someContactId
```

and to update you would perform the following:

```
update a
   set a.address1='27 Foo Street'
from
   addresses as a
   join contacts as c
       on a.id=c.addressId
where c.id=@someContactId
```

It's rarely a good idea to duplicate data in a database. Search around for the term database normalization for more info on this subject.

Comment: The data is only duplicated in a temporary table, I'm using the data that it contains for updates on multiple (non-temporary) tables.

Comment: ok, but you should be able to structure your db such that using a temp table is not required. the update join pattern is a fairly powerful means of achieving this on a we designed schema

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 'spender' - you shouldn't be duplicating this data.

If you must, however, do a batch update, this is the T-SQL statement you'd use:

```
UPDATE dbo.Contacts
SET addr1 = address1,
    addr2 = address2
FROM dbo.Addresses
WHERE id = contact
```

You just join the Contacts table to the Addresses table by defining the `WHERE id = contact` clause and then you set the addr1/addr2 fields on the Contacts table to the corresponding values of address1/address2 on the Addresses table - pretty simple, huh?

Marc